# Android SwipeRefreshLayout Spinner hides before completion

Tags: android, kotlin, swiperefreshlayout

I have managed to implement the **SwipeRefreshLayout** in my project, and it works as expected, executing the callback code, displaying the spinner, and reloading the relevant data. And it works time and again without issue.

However, the problem is, whenever I perform the **pull-down** gesture, the spinner is pulled down correctly, turning clockwise in sync with the pull gesture, but it **immediately jumps back to the top once the touch is released**, even before the callback process has completed. This is how it's been implemented:

```
tableRefresh = SwipeRefreshLayout(this)
tableRefresh?.setOnRefreshListener {
    tableRefresh?.isRefreshing = true
    swipeRefreshHandler()
}

// global Intent
var cloudService: Intent? = null

private fun swipeRefreshHandler() {
    // starts a server-update service
    startService(cloudService?.setAction(serverManualSync))
}

cloudServiceBroadcastReceiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        when (intent?.action) {

            // server-update service notifies of completion
            serverManualSyncComplete -> tableRefresh?.isRefreshing = false

            // other cases

        }

    }

}
```

Again, there is no problem with the *functionality* per se, just that the spinner does not remain visible for the duration of the callback. And it works on every consecutive pull gesture.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: can u show all the codes related to swiperefreshlayout and async call? That'll be more effective.

Comment: @HeinHtetAung OK. I've expanded the code in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are setting the `SwipeRefreshLayout` to stop refreshing immediately.

The `swipeRefreshHandler()` method is called directly.

Instead, you should listen to when the callback process is completed then set the `isRefreshing` to false.

Could you show the relevant callback code? Perhaps it is running asynchronously?

Comment: Actually, the given code has been slightly abbreviated. And you're right; the callback is asynchronous, retrieving data from a cloud server. But the `isRefreshing` property is set to false only after the server has responded and the relevant updates made. Furthermore, the spinner still springs back even if the `isRefreshing` property is not set to false. I have also tried replacing the server code with a blocking math calculation running in a long loop, but again, still the same results; the spinner just does not stick.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could look something like this:

```
tableRefresh = SwipeRefreshLayout(this)

 tableRefresh?.setOnRefreshListener {
 swipeRefreshHandler()
}

private fun swipeRefreshHandler(loadingState: Boolean = true) {
  if(loadingState){
    //
    // code to reload the data...
    //        
  }
  sideMenuRefresh?.isRefreshing = loadingState
}
```

then in you async call (using coroutines or retrofit for example), you can call

```
swipeRefreshHandler() // loading state for ongoing operation
```

OR

```
swipeRefreshHandler(false) // when data or process completed (success/fail)
```

Comment: Yes; actually that's what I'm doing. The **reload** code is an asynchronous call to a cloud server, and the `isRefreshing` property is set to false in the server response section of the code. But, even **without** setting the `isRefreshing` property to false, the spinner does not stay for the duration of the reload process.

Comment: Mind if i go over a few basics just to cover possibilities, have registered you BR in the activity before making call to service using: registerReceiver(), have you created an intent filter and added it you your receiver via : registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter), broadcast intents using sendBroadcast()

Comment: Yes; all intents have been registered and is being sent/received correctly. There are no issues with functionality. Just that annoying little spinner that refuses to stay put.

Comment: I hear you  :), my final suggestion is create a mock test, like a thread that sleeps for a few seconds or handler with delay and put your UI (spinner) logic in it don;t make network calls, just to determine is the issue is with server calls or the logic handling the swipe to refresh spinner